# Bootstrap dialog won't show

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a simple popup log in form using Bootstrap. I'm following this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCEbp07hfLw
So I'm trying to do what he is doing with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>kaki</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
<script type="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">        </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="modal" id="myModal" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Poop and Kaki Login</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="span4"/><br/>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="span4"><br/><br/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log In</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn">Clear</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code nothing at all shows up.. Nothing.

Comment: You need to include jQuery *before* Bootstrap's JS. Did you check for errors in the browser console?

Comment: I just tried the jQuery before Bootstrap and it didnt do anything... The console wrote: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: sounds like your jQuery is not loading properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a working modal in bootstrap: http://jsfiddle.net/chapmanc/d518cdwt/1/
    
    
      Launch demo modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

One problem is that you are using a bootstrap version which requires a minimum version 1.9.1 of jQuery where you are including 1.7.1.

Another issue is that modals are hidden by default and you never actually launch the modal. If you look at the example I linked to which was pulled from the documentation you'll see a button to launch the modal.

My advice would be to always read the documentation of what you're looking into (some docs are better than others but bootstrap's is very good). Also you should get familiar with the browser debug tools, specifically the console. I prefer Chrome, https://developer.chrome.com/devtools.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap modals does not automagically open. You should just use the unobtrusive JS as mentioned in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo) to trigger the modal window:

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Comment: I tried that and I still have the same results.. Pressing the trigger button does nothing

Comment: Please create a sample so people can take a look at it.